# How do I skip a subsection?

Tags: sectioning

How do I skip a subsection (in this case, 1.2) like this:

```
1 Main Title
1.1 Subtitle
1.3 Subtitle
1.4 Subtitle
```

Comment: David, not all and everything  technically possible is good. Why in the world would you skip a number?

Comment: @KeksDose -- maybe the document in question is quoting just segments from another (numbered) document, and it's important to keep the original numbering.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've been reading and (once in a while) answering LaTeX questions in a German forum which used to be the place to go for many students. After a while I noticed that many students had »Procrustean« views: if it doesn't fit, I'll make it fit. So I started to ask for the students reasons to do strange things and tried to make them listen to sense...

Comment: @KeksDose -- it's never a bad idea (and usually a good one) to know *why* something is "necessary".  so keep on asking.  (i find i learn interesting things when i do.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`\stepcounter` or `\addtocounter` can be used, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Main Title}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\stepcounter{subsection}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]